# bootstrapped standard error to make inference about difference of means

Tags: mean, bootstrap, standard-error, median

I have a variable showing individual wages and a categorical variable of their race (Hispanic, Asian, etc). After getting their means, medians and their respective standard errors for each group separately by non-parametric bootstrapping, how can I use the bootstrapped standard errors to make inference about Hispanics' wages compared to the other groups. Can I use the mean or median confidence interval from the bootstrap and compare with each group, or do I have necessarily to have bootstrapped t values (with pairwise difference of means)?

Comment: Was there a particular reason you used bootstrapping for this? Rather than using the aggregated data for wages by race from the bootstrap you can do the _comparisons_ within each bootstrapped sample to get estimates of the confidence intervals for the comparisons.

Comment: What I did before was having samples of wages for each group separately, so that at the end I have 5 different distributions of wages for each group and like that I can the mean and standard error for each group. Do you mean  estimate first the difference of means for each bootstrap sample (comparing Hispanic with each group) and then taking the mean and standard deviation of all these difference of means?

Comment: Effectively yes, do the differences of the means sample-by-sample and then pool the differences to get estimates of their variability. You might consider combining wages for all races (appropriately tagged by race) to model sampling among races. If you do enough bootstrap samples you can get 95% confidence intervals for the differences more-or-less directly. As there are some differences of opinion about the most appropriate way to get confidence intervals from bootstrapping, the `boot.ci` function in the R `boot` package provides several ways to calculate them.